# At which points is the following function differentiable

Tags: calculus

The following function is a standard example for a function whose points of discontinuity are strange:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}1/q& \mbox{ if } x=p/q \mbox{ and }p/q \mbox{ is a fully reduced fraction}\\ 0& \mbox{ if }x \mbox{ is irrational} \end{cases}.$

So I wanted to modify this example to the function

$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}1/q^n& \mbox{ if } x=p/q \mbox{ and }p/q \mbox{ is a fully reduced fraction}\\ 0& \mbox{ if }x \mbox{ is irrational} \end{cases}.$

and ask for which $x$ this function is differentiable (depending on $n$)?

Comment: Is $g_n(x)$ continuous ?

Comment: @Henrik Panja has a point: *first* try to find the points where your function is continuous, as this is usually easier to do....there are not many of these in this case  :)

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: It is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n >0$.

Comment: @ Shalop): So question of differentiability arises only at irrational points ...

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make sense to talk about differentiability elsewhere.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the examples with $f$. Most things will go just fine with $g_n$ for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$g_n$ is continuos precisely at the irrationals. If $g_n'(x)$ exists, then certainly $x$ is irrational and $g_n'(x)=0$. The definition of derivative at such an $x$ becomes equivalent to $q^n|\frac pq-x|\to 0$ as $\frac pq\to x$. 
The question is how good an irrational $x$ can be approximated by rationals. If $x$ is algebraic then $|x-\frac pq|<\frac c{q^2}$ has only finitely many solutions (if we pick $c>0$ small enough). Hence $g_n'(x)$ exists for algebraic irrational $x$ iff $n\ge 3$. 
For transcendental $x$, the mileage *may* vary.

Comment: I guess you meant $q^n|x-p/q| \rightarrow \infty$ as $p/q \rightarrow x$ (that is the denominator of the term whose limit gives the derivative).

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to choose other functions of $q$ (than $q^n$) so that the answer depends on the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$...